# Is there any way to define a programming function not mathematic one?

Tags: functions

I want to define a programming function, as I understood in Mathematica we can define it as Module. Is there any way to pack this code in a Module and call it n time to plot n time m v , Y
like in range 1,n?
I just want to compare the results for different n.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
Clear["Global`*"]
n = 5;
y = Sum[x^i*a[i], {i, 2, n}];
th = D[y, x];
M = EI*D[y, {x, 2}];
V = EI*D[y, {x, 3}];
PE = EI/2*Integrate[(D[y, {x, 2}])^2, {x, 0, L}] - 
   Integrate[q*(x/L)*y, {x, 0, L}];
Eq = Table[D[PE, a[i]], {i, 1, n}];
sol = Solve[Eq == 0, Array[a, n]]
Y = y /. sol
th /. sol
Eq /. sol;
m = FullSimplify[M /. sol[[1]]]
v = FullSimplify[V /. sol[[1]]]
EI = 100;
q = -1;
L = 10;
Plot[{m}, {x, 0, L}, AxesLabel -> {"x (m)", "M (N.m.)"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Style[" M", Bold, 12]}]
Plot[{v}, {x, 0, L}, AxesLabel -> {"x (m)", "V (N/m^2.)"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Style[" V", Bold, 12]}]
Plot[{Y}, {x, 0, L}, AxesLabel -> {"x (m)", "Y (m)"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Style[" Y", Bold, 12]}]
```

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To define a function you should clarify what you want as the input and output. As an alternative, you can use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

EI = 100;
q = -1;
L = 10;

Manipulate[
  y = Sum[x^i*a[i], {i, 2, n}];
  th = D[y, x];
  M = EI*D[y, {x, 2}];
  V = EI*D[y, {x, 3}];
  PE = EI/2*Integrate[(D[y, {x, 2}])^2, {x, 0, L}] - 
    Integrate[q*(x/L)*y, {x, 0, L}];
  Eq = Table[D[PE, a[i]], {i, 1, n}];
  sol = Solve[Eq == 0, Array[a, n]];
  Y = y /. sol;
  th /. sol;
  Eq /. sol;
  m = FullSimplify[M /. sol[[1]]];
  v = FullSimplify[V /. sol[[1]]];
  Column[{
    StringForm["M = ``", m],
    StringForm["V = ``", v],
    StringForm["Y = ``", Y[[1]]],
    Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip /@ {m, v, Y}], {x, 0, L},
     AxesLabel -> {Style["x (m)", 12, Bold], None},
     PlotLegends -> Placed[
       (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"M (N.m.)", "V (N/m^2)", "Y (m)"}),
       {0.7, 0.35}],
     ImageSize -> Medium]}],
  {{n, 5, Style["n", 12, Bold]}, 3, 6, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}] // 
Quiet
```

[image]